# Testing grep exit status with pipe and variable unsuccessful

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, brackets

I need as short as possible bash test command (bracket test) to evaluate result of piped grep with variable as search argument. I am testing, whether a new string is in the array - piping the array contents as lines to grep and checking exit code. But it somehow does not work. Does not find the value in the array. I have tried in various ways brackets, parenthesis, quotes, semicolons with no luck.
What is wrong here?

```
#! /bin/bash
startLineNrs=();
startLineNrs+=("45");
startLineNrs+=("280");
startLineNrs+=("80");
startLineNr="280";
echo "\$startLineNrs:" ${#startLineNrs[@]};
printf '%s\n' "${startLineNrs[@]}";
[ "$(printf '%s\n' ${startLineNrs[@]} | grep -xq ${startLineNr})" ] && { echo $?; echo Found ;} || { echo $?; echo Not found ;}
```

Basically I want to understand the if...then construct versus the brackets test. The if...then method works:

```
if !( printf '%s\n' "${startLineNrs[@]}" | grep -xq "${startLineNr}" ); then startLineNrs+=("$startLineNr") ; fi
```

Comment: FYI, `$?` only returns the pipe's last exit status, if you had a longer series of pipes you might want $PIPESTATUS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the `&&`--`||` command work, try:

```
printf '%s\n' ${startLineNrs[@]} | grep -xq ${startLineNr}  && { echo $?; echo Found ;} || { echo $?; echo Not found ;}
```

Notes:

1. The test command (`[`) and the command substitution (`$(...)`) are not needed.
2. A subtlety of the construct `a && b || c` is that `c` will be executed not just if `a` fails but also if `b` fails.  Since your `b` consists of `echo` statements which should normally succeed, this should not normally be a problem.
3. For other methods for testing array membership, see ["Check if a Bash array contains a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value).

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to write your if statement is:

```
if printf '%s\n' "${startLineNrs[@]}" | grep -xq "$startLineNr"; then
  # your logic
fi
```

The issue with your test statement `[...]` is that `[` or `test` treats `"$(printf '%s\n' ${startLineNrs[@]} | grep -xq ${startLineNr})` as a string, and it doesn't run it as a command substitution.  Since it is a non-empty string, it will always evaluate to true.